# How fast is mobile internet in Malaysia?

Tags: internet, malaysia

So on my trip to Malaysia, I'm thinking about getting a prepaid sim when I get there. I don't really need the ability to phone but I would like it to have data.

I want to use it to use Google Maps to navigate around, call home and do some emailing / web browsing in the evening etc. I don't anticipate I'll be using a whole lot of data.

I also notice that some of the places I'm planning to stay in Georgetown Penang has some reviewers saying the wifi is down a lot.

So I guess the question is if I get one a prepaid sim card, r the mobile networks reliable enough that I'll be able to use it on the go and also not need to rely on the wifi? Esp. in Georgetown Malaysia?

Comment: Pretty decent, not different than Europe IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, yes. You will not have a problem using Malaysian cellular internet for Google Maps, e-mail, web browsing, etc.

Longer answer, the mobile networks are reliable enough that  you should be able to use a prepaid cell phone for voice and data in most areas. Just like many countries, there are places you will not get reception such as jungles and other sparsely populated areas. Even urban areas have dead zones, in Malaysia and in other countries. Additionally, different carriers have different coverage.

Georgetown is a reasonably well developed area. You should be good.

Comment: Not in my experience...

Comment: This also depends on your carrier.  I've found Maxis to be pretty good, but YMMV.

Comment: I've found different carriers are better in some places than others.  In KL (and probably George Town) you should be able to get 4G from all the main providers